# Why are Iranian universities ranked better than Turkish universities?

Tags: ranking, iran, turkey

The following is the [Times Higher Education world university ranking 2021](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2021/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/locations/IR+TR/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats):

[image]

According to this ranking, Iranian universities rank higher than that of Turkey.

Is there any specific reason, given that Iran is under sanction for years, and almost disconnected from the western world. On the other hand, Turkey is well-connected to the EU and Bologna process?

Comment: School rankings cluster very closely, and even more so farther down the list. In the US, Tulane, Temple, UT Knoxville, and Boston College are in the 301-350 range; UGA, University of Kentucky, Iowa State, and University of Connecticut are 401-500. Is UT Knoxville a better school than UGA, UK, or UConn? That may be true in some programs, but I wouldn't say that generally. They all feel comparable to me. I'd take middle increments in rankings like this with a grain of salt.

Comment: I wouldn't put too much weight on these kinds of results.  Ranking individual departments maybe makes a little more sense, but it would be difficult to do across all academic cultures in the world.  Ranking entire universities around the world is a fraught endeavor - a glance at the methodology shows the largest part of the weighting comes from a survey of opinions.  Which is then used to publish a list, to influence opinions...

Comment: To back up @Jeff's comment: the methodology of the ranking is explained [here](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/world-university-rankings-2021-methodology). Here are some highlights: Half (!) of the teaching ranking comes from a global "reputation survey", and even 60% of the research ranking are determined by a "reputation survey", too. This has some remarkable consequences. [to be continued]

Comment: [continuation] For instance, I just had a look at the scores for all ranked Germany universities, and there is apparently an extremely high correlation between the teaching score and the research score. Given the specifics of the German educational system, this is not particularly plausible (to put it mildly). What we most likely see here is simply the reputation that people around the world associate with a given university, and it's quite likely that most peope answering these surveys do not distinguish well between research quality and teaching quality.